# Client-id : j_id10 is duplicated in the faces tree. Component

Tags: jsf, runtime-error

I am facing this issue for a part of my JSF1.2 application. I have a upload functionality and the listing of files on the later part of the page.After log in, if the first function I do is upload file, it comes back with the erro - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client-id : j_id10 is duplicated in the faces tree. Component.
BUt if i browse the application, do some other function first and then try upload, it works fine.
Also the upload function was done using servlet, since JSF1.2 does not provide any tag for file/multipart  upload.

The UI  have upload and file listing using Data table.

Stripped code --

rowClasses="alt-color,alt-text1" styleClass="table-boder1" columnClasses="=alt-text1" >

```
<h:column  id="fileName" headerClass="head-1">
    <f:facet name="header">

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.filename}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{filedata.fileName}"/>


</h:column>


<h:column id="controlTotal" headerClass="head-2" rendered="#{fileManager.selectedLobUser}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.controltotal}"/>
    </f:facet>
........
```

,..............

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this possibly by reasons:
-If you are using more then one form element you need to assign "cId" with different value
-please check whole page have duplicate IDs (including composition)

Comment: Really cId? Not id?